# Cauchy-Riemann necessary and sufficient conditions for derivative to exist?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading Complex Analysis and there is a theorem in my notes which seems incorrect to me.I searched this on MSE site and found one or two similar poorly framed questions with not so great answers . So , i am posting a new one here.

> The necessary and sufficient conditions for derivative to exist at a
> certain point in a complex-valued function is the satisfaction of
> Cauchy-Reimann conditions .

**There is also proof of the above given ,if the community asks then i    will edit and add the picture of the proof.**

Now, i applied this theorem in below question.

*Show that the Cauchy-Reimann equations are satisfied at the origin and check its differentiability at the origin.*
$$f(z)=\sqrt|xy|  $$
Now , i calculated $u_x$, $u_y$ ,$v_x$,$v_y$ by their standard definitions and all of them come out to be $0$ , which going by this theorem suggests that the function is differentiable at the origin. However , when i calculate the derivative using standard definition of complex differentiability along some radial direction say $y=mx$, the derivative depends upon the value of $m$ which suggests that the derivative doesn't exist which is a contradiction.

Any help from the community is appreciated.

Comment: $f=u+iv$ is differentiable iff $u$, $v$ are differentiable *and* the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold. In your case, $u$ isn't differentiable at $0$, as you've discovered.

Comment: @jlammy should i post picture of proof ?

Comment: A correct result is that on an open set complex differentiability and C-R are equivalent for a continuous function with no extra conditions (where CR means only that the partial derivatives in cause exist on the open set and satisfy the required identities; no other assumptions needed as either complex differentiability or C-R on an open set imply strong regularity for the function); on non-open sets (eg isolated points) things are tricky and one needs stronger regularity conditions in the hypothesis

Comment: see Looman Menchoff theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem and examples thereof

Comment: @Conrad, i get some idea. An open set is a set in which each point is an interior point ?

Comment: yes - there are a lot of subtle versions of the result (eg the function can be assumed to be locally bounded rather than continuous) but continuity is needed as Looman's example shows